# branding questions (masterpage, css, etc.)

Tags: css, branding

I have the following wire frame for our homepage. I would like to know what page to start with (wiki, web part pages as I am planning on list for news, announces, frequently used links and external links, and free time web part). New to branding. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Version of SharePoint?

Comment: SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would recommend you

- You should start planning your css and what you want to change.
- Try to get a Front developer with experience in styles in sharepoint because you will be ahead of the game.
- If you are using VS 2012 to develop your solutions be sure to deploy first Lists Projects, then webparts, the Master pages (layouts, styles, etc) and finally Pages.

Hope this helps

Comment: I got the layout concepts using SP Designer. I dont want to use visual studio method. Can you tell me how to create look and feel for the list (like I posted in the OP)?

Comment: Hi. I wouldn't recommend you using SP designer 2013 because they have removed the design view. In any case, use SP designer 2010 because I think is easier to use.
Check this link out because I think that you have there all you need. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/82905/A-Visual-Guide-in-designing-Sharepoint-2010